# Is there any opposite of include? method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question: Is there any opposite method of `.include?` I know with `unless`, but I want to do it with `if`, can I? I tried with `unless`:

```
unless variable.include?("something")
#..
end
```

I want to do it with `if`, can I? I know `.!include?` but it didn't work(i don't really know if this method exists, but I saw it in this forum).

Comment: Short answer: Not in vanilla ruby, but `exclude?` exists in ActiveSupport - which is mainly used by Rails applications.

Comment: `!include?` are actually _two_ methods: [`!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) and `include?` You therefore have to write `!variable.include?` instead of `variable.!include?`

Answer (score 7):

```
if !variable.include?("something")
```

in plain Ruby

```
if variable.exclude?("something")
```

in Rails